# Javascript Hoisting : difference between calling x and window.x

Tags: javascript, hoisting

Can anyone explain the hoisting behavior in the below scenarios?

```
alert(x);
var x = 10;

Result: alert-undefined
```

In the below case, x is not defined using 'var' keyword - hence attaches to the global scope.

```
alert(x);
x = 10; // not given a var

Result: error
```

In case if we replace x with window.x, we get alert as undefined!

```
alert(window.x); // calling the variable with window namespace
x = 10; // not given a var

Result: alert-undefined
```

Can you explain why it is different in calling a variable (which is attached to global scope) with the variable name (x) and with window namespace (window.x)?

Comment: Have you tried the same procedure with `window["x"]`?

Comment: @TomDoodler `window["x"]` is equal to `window.x` so it would not make a difference.

Comment: alert(x);
var x = 10; is equal to var x; alert(x); x=10; so first one is undefined

Comment: Use `"use strict"` if you want a coherent behavior.

Comment: For completeness, [this post](http://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2013/04/20/javascript-hoisting-explained/) actually describes more weird behaviour in JS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term "hoisting" is often misunderstood to mean that certain statements are moved to the top of their execution context, which is not what happens and why the term should be avoided.

What actually happens is that all declarations are processed first, so any variable declared with *var* (and any function created by a function declaration) exists before any code is executed. Then code execution begins.

So the variable *x* is created and assigned the value *undefined* before any code is executed (per ECMA-262), then later, during execution, it may be assigned some value.

So in the case of:

```
alert(x);
var x = 10;
```

*x* exists when *alert* is called, but has yet to be assigned a value other than *undefined*.

In:

```
alert(x);
x = 10;
```

*x* is not declared, so it does not exist when *alert* is called, hence the error. After the alert (if the code kept running), the assignment to *x* would create a property of the global (window in a browser) object named *x* and assign it a value of 10.

In:

```
alert(window.x);
x = 10;
```

It is a quirk of ECMAScript that global variables are also available as properties of the global object. The expression `window.x` attempts to read the *x* property of the window object. Since no such property exists, the return is *undefined*. Then the next statement creates *x* as a global variable and hence *window.x* now exists with a value of 10.

Comment: Thanks @RobG, so its not just about window.x, its valid for any undeclared variables window.a, window.b... etc :D

Comment: Yes. *window.x* is resolving a property name on an object, which has different rules to resolving an identifier within an execution context and scope chain. In the first case, if the property doesn't exist, you get *undefined*. In the second, an error is thrown. Why? Because that's what the specification says should happen. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

`var x` hoists the variable in the entire scope it's valid in, so *the name* `x` is available and valid anywhere within the scope. Its initial value is `undefined`, it only receives its value after the alert.

In case of a plain `x`, the variable is not hoisted because there's no `var`, so the bubbling up to `window` and its creation there only happens on the line `x = 10`, which is after the alert, which means the variable is entirely undefined and invalid at the time you try to alert it.

Any non-existing property of any object returns `undefined`, so testing `window.x` at a time when that property isn't set returns `undefined` as expected. That's how you do membership testing in Javascript: check whether a specific property equals `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, `var x` gets hoisted, so `x` does exist when you call it (even though the value is undefined)

In the second case, when you say `y = 10`, you're essentially saying `window.y = 10`, so there's no hoisting at all, that's why it can't find the variable at all and gives you an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(x);
var x = 10;
```

will treated as

```
var x;
alert(x);
x = 10;
```

So at the time of `alert` `x` has the value `undefined` by `default`;

```
alert(x);
x = 10;
```

will be treated as

```
alert(x);
x = 10; // If this line runs in use strict mode then this line will throw error otherwise in non strict mode x will be added to global object ie. window
```

So will `throw error` because of `x` is `undefined` at the time of `alert`

```
alert(window.x); 
x = 10;
```

will be treated as

```
alert(window.x);
x = 10;
```

alert will alert `undefined` because `window` is an `object` and it is having no property named as `x` at the time of `alert` so `undefined`
Later the line `x = 10;` will add the `x` to `global object` if in `non strict mode`, and will `throw error` if in `strict mode`